# Folding in array mutations using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have 218k+ 33-channel images, and I need to find the mean and variance of each channel. I've tried to use multiprocessing, but this seems unbearably slow. Here's a brief code sample:

```
def work(aggregates, genput):
    # received (channel, image) from generator
    channel = genput[0]
    image = genput[1]
    for row in image:
        for pixel in row:
            # use welford's to update a list of "aggregates" which will
            # later be finalized as means and variances of each channel
            aggregates[channel] = update(aggregates[channel], pixel)

def data_stream(df, data_root):
    '''Generator that returns the channel and image for each tif file'''
    for index, sample in df.iterrows():
        curr_img_path = data_root

        # read the image with all channels
        tif = imread(curr_img_path)  #33x64x64 array        
        for channel, image in enumerate(tif):
            yield (channel, image)     

# Pass over each image, compute mean/variance for each channel for each image
def preprocess_mv(df, data_root, channels=33, multiprocessing=True):
    '''Calculates mean and variance on the whole image set for use in deep_learn'''
    manager = Manager()
    aggregates = manager.list()

    [aggregates.append(([0,0,0])) for i in range(channels)]

    proxy = partial(work, aggregates)

    pool = Pool(processes=8) 
    pool.imap(proxy, data_stream(df, data_root), chunksize=5000)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # finalize data below
```

My suspicion is that the time it takes to pickle the `aggregates` array and transfer that back and forth from parent to child processes takes a horrendously long time, and that this is the major bottleneck - I could see this drawback completely eliminating the multi-process advantage since each child is having to wait for other children to pickle and unpickle data. I've read that this is sort of a limitation of the multiprocessing library, and from the pieces I've put together reading other posts here, I've come to realize this may be the best I can do. That said, does anyone have suggestions for how this could be improved?

Additionally, I'm wondering if there are better libraries/tools for this task? A friend actually recommended Scala and I have been investigating that as an option. I'm just very familiar with Python and would like to stay in this domain if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come to a solution by exploring `multiprocessing.Array` a little more in depth. I had to figure out how to convert my 2D array to a 1D array and still make indexing work out, but this ended up being pretty simple math. I can now process 1000 samples in 2 minutes instead of 4 hours, so I think that's pretty nice. I also had to write a custom function to print the array, but that's fairly straight forward. This implementation doesn't guarantee against race conditions, but for my purposes this works fairly well. You could easily add a lock by including it in init and passing it in the same way you do with the array (using `global`).

```
def init(arr):
    global aggregates
    aggregates = arr

def work(genput):
    # received (sample, channel, image) from generator
    sample_no = genput[0]
    channel = genput[1]
    image = genput[2]
    currAgg =  (aggregates[3*channel], aggregates[3*channel+1], 
                aggregates[3*channel+2])
    for row in image:
        for pixel in row:
            # use welford's to compute updated aggregate
            newAgg = update(currAgg, pixel)
            currAgg = newAgg
    # New method of indexing for 1D array ("shaped" as 33x3)
    aggregates[3*channel] = newAgg[0]
    aggregates[(3*channel)+1] = newAgg[1]
    aggregates[(3*channel)+2] = newAgg[2]

def data_stream(df, data_root):
    '''Generator that returns the channel and image for each tif file'''
    ...
    yield (index, channel, image)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    aggs = Array('d', np.zeros(99)) #99 values for all aggrs

    pool = Pool(initializer=init, initargs=(aggs,), processes=8)
    pool.imap(work, data_stream(df, data_root), chunksize=10)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

#-----------finalize aggregates below
```

Comment: That looks like a pretty nice way to avoid serialization overhead for `aggregates`, but I'd suggest that there might also be an opportunity to avoid sending the image data between processes. If you changed `data_stream` to just yield file names, the worker could load and split them by channel itself.

Comment: This is true. I also discovered that I can pass in a dictionary of locks (one per channel) as a global variable, and so any operation on any channel can be thread-safe without blocking access to all of `aggregates`. Tonight I think I will rework this so each process just gets an image path and then acquires locks as necessary to write to the correct section of `aggregates`.